# Сертификаты java от oracle

Tags: java

На сколько мне известно что большинства сертификатов не имеют никакого смысла. Но в то же время слышал что некий вес имеют сертификаты от oracle, вопрос в следующем, имеет ли смысл проходить сертификацию от оракла, с целью привлекательной строчки в резюме(На данный момент нигде не работал), имею в виду самый базовый сертификат Associate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сдавал 2 экзамена для получения Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 7

- плюсы: изучаются все конструкции языка (синтаксис), API в комплекте SE, множество нюансов и устройство языка
- минусы: высокая цена (150 долларов за экзамен, но частенько можно найти промо коды для получения скидки 10-30%), скорее всего нужно будет отдельно покупать mock экзамены, для успешной сдачи с высоким процентом правильных ответов

Сертификаты имеют вес, потому что получить их не так просто и без подготовки практически невозможно. Процедура сдачи экзаменов очень строгая. Вопросов много, времени мало. Для следующей ступени (мастерской) требуется хорошее знание письменного английского языка

Comment: я провильно понял, ты платил за каждый из экзаменов порядка 150$? Задания былина английском?

Comment: @АндрейКозицкий В сумме вышло 250$. Задания на английском, регистрация тоже. Сдача проходит в сертифицированном (для pearson vue) аттестационном центре, который есть не в каждом городе. Без мок экзаменов лучше не пробовать сдавать, наводка по ключевому слову enthuware